# Big motor vehicle's body vibration

Tags: building-physics

What is the main cause of vehicles like cheaply designed busses to vibrate it's whole body at high or low engine RPMs??

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. I think this you should also post this question on [Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) as it seems more relevant to engineering than physics.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here are three factors, playing a role in the vibration of vehicles, there might be more but these are I can think of at the moment:

1 - Resonance frequencies

2 - Damping

3 - Radial forces

Every body oscillates at some frequency. If an outer influence has the same frequency the amplitude of the oscillations will increase significantly. So each element in a vehicle can resonate at a certain RPM of the engine. It might be that the frame of the vehicle resonates at low RPM, so that is why it feels very shaky at low RPM.

There are damping elements, designed to disperse the energy of the mechanical waves as heat energy, but the damping elements are not universal and need to be picked, depending on where they will be used.

Radial forces, as a result of an imbalanced rotation are proportional to the square of the RPM of the body, so vibrations at high RPM are very likely to be as a result of imbalanced rotations.

Vehicle vibrations can be caused by any combination of these factors.

You were talking about *RPM* and not *speeds* so I assume you mean a stationary vehicle. At high *speeds* there might be other factors, maybe low-quality suspension.